# Inserting Polygon data into MySQL table using NodeJs and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert polygon data (lat-longs) obtained through a user selection on the map.

My sequelize table field is -

```
"use strict";
    var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        var MapData = sequelize.define("MapData ", {
                mapDataId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey : true
                },     
                mySelection: {
                    type: 'Polygon',
                    allowNull: true
                },       
                createdByUserId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull : false
                },
                createdDate: {
                    type: DataTypes.DATE,
                    allowNull : false
                },
                modifiedByUserId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull : false
                },
                modifiedDate: {
                    type: DataTypes.DATE,
                    allowNull : false
                },
            },
            {
                tableName:'MapData',
                timestamps:false
            });

        return MapData ;
    };
```

The NodeJs server code is

```
create:function(mapData, creatorId){

        mapData.createdDate = new Date();
        mapData.modifiedDate = new Date();
        mapData.createdByUserId = creatorId;
        mapData.modifiedByUserId = creatorId;
        mapData.mySelection =  { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [
            [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
                [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
        ]};     
        MapData.create(mapData) }
```

This does not get inserted into the table. I referred to the sequelize documentation but found it confusing. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have not done this myself but after reading the docs, you have the type of mySelection wrong. It should be `DataTypes.GEOMETRY`. `GEOMETRY` type is supported by MySQL and Postgres with PostGIS module only.